# SharedPreference gets cleared while navigating through one activity to another

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using `SharedPreference` to store my id, but it does not work.

When app launches in Activity-A, I am storing id in prefs, and then go to Activity-B.
In my Activity-B I have one button, on click of button I am going back to Activity-A, and I see that the id which I stored was not in preferece

Activity-A

```
         @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


    editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    editor.putString("yourtextvalueKey", id);
    editor.commit();

    prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    text= prefs.getString("yourtextvalueKey", null);
    System.out.println("text of id"+text);
```

Activity-B

```
 backaro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityA.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: This shouldn't happen.Could you post your full activity code?

Comment: It can't be. In which method you are trying to save data and in which method you are retrieving it.

Comment: That's why I asked to show the full code. Could you?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:** You are getting the value from intent and saving it. Initially it gets saved and you can see that. But, when you move back to `ActivityA` on button click of `ActivityB` you don't pass any value to the intent. Which means `id` becomes null and it gets saved. So you are getting `null` as result.

Update your code like this

```
id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
if(id != null){
    editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    editor.putString("yourtextvalueKey", id);
    editor.commit();
}
prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0);
text= prefs.getString("yourtextvalueKey", null);
System.out.println("text of id"+text);
```

**Update:** You could also pass an value in intent when you start activity on button click and you will get that value. But if you don't want to sent any value then you need to check it first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888835/intent-share-not-working-with-image-and-text-sharing

Comment: can you tell abot that?

Answer (score -1):

just replace apply with commit()

```
id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

        editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        editor.putString("yourtextvalueKey", id);
        editor.commit();

        prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        text= prefs.getString("yourtextvalueKey", null);
        System.out.println("text of id"+text);
```